# Group By multiple columns in Linq statement

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

Below is my linq query :

```
var objList = from p in db.Table1
              join q in db.Table2 on p.saleCategoryId equals q.Id
              join r in db.Table3 on p.landDetailId equals r.Id
              select new
              {
               p.Id,
               r.KhataNo,
               r.KhasraNo,
               q.type,
               p.saleCategoryId,
               p.area,
               p.stock
              };
```

From above query I have a result like below :

```
Id  KhataNo  KhasraNo  Type SaleCategoryId  Area  Stock
1     1AB     11AB      LOM     1            100   50
2     1AB     11AB      LOR     2            200  100
3     1CD     11CD      LOM     1            300  150
4     1CD     11CD      LOR     2            250   50
```

But I want to group by and summing up few columns above in following way (desired output) :

```
Id   KhataNo   KhasraNo  Area  Stock
1     1AB       11AB      300   150
2     1CD       11CD      550   200
```

Anyone can help me please to get the desired output.

Comment: @learningNew this is sum of stock value in a group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
      var objList = from p in db.Table1
          join q in db.Table2 on p.saleCategoryId equals q.Id
          join r in db.Table3 on p.landDetailId equals r.Id
          group t by new{t.KhataNo, t.KhasraNo}
          into grp
          select new
          {

           grp.key.KhataNo,
           grp.key.KhasraNo,
           area = grp.Sum(t=> t.Table1.area),
           stock = grp.Sum(t=>t.Table1.stock)
          };
```

Comment: sorry .. i have mistaken.. actually instead of above line I am not able to sum from Table1.. the line where you had mentioned grp.Sum(t => t.area) , area column is from Table1. and it is not accessible.

Comment: try this: area = grp.Sum(t=>t.Table1.area)

Comment: thanks .. one thing i want to ask you if i have to get inique id (primary key) from Table1 then how should i coded it in query... is it as grp.Key ?? Or ??

Comment: If my answer is correct then please mark it as answer

Comment: I don't think you can get primary key in select clause after grouping, I would suggest to add an integer number for each row in resultset after getting result from this query..

Comment: Or I guess something like this should work:  grp.FirstOrDefault().Id

Comment: yes actually i was just about to mark it as answer.. but i had to go somewhere.. thanks for d help. but what if i need to get Table1.Id so that i can bind all the details on basis of that Id.